# transferFrom function works but approve does not

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, dapps

I'm building an escrow contract and using web3js to interact with it. Currently, I am trying to approve and send an amount of custom ERC20 token from a wallet to the escrow contract. The problem is, the approve function doesn't work, but the transferFrom function that I call from the escrow contract itself does. I know the approve function doesn't work because I check the allowance from Remix and it shows none. Why does one transaction work and not the other?

Transaction Data:

```
//This doesnt work
    let approveSpender = async(batch=false) => {

                const txOptions = {
                    from: address_from,
                    nonce: await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address_from, "pending"),
                    gasLimit: web3.toHex(210000),
                    gasPrice:web3.toHex(web3.toWei('30', 'gwei')),
                    to: gntAddress,
                    data :gntContract.approve.getData(escrowAddress, (40e18)),
                    value: "0x0",
                };
                let transaction = new EthereumTx(txOptions);

                if(batch) return sendRaw(transaction);

                const txResult = await sendRaw(transaction);
                if(!txResult) {console.error('Something messed up')}
                else console.log('Actually worked?');
            };
//This works
    let depositToEscrow = async(batch=false) => {
                let nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address_from, "pending");
                if(batch) nonce += 1;

                const txOptions = {
                    from: address_from,
                    nonce: nonce,
                    gasLimit: web3.toHex(210000),
                    gasPrice:web3.toHex(web3.toWei('30', 'gwei')),
                    to: escrowAddress,
                    data :escrowContract.deposit.getData((40*1e18)),
                    value: "0x0",

                };
                let transaction = new EthereumTx(txOptions);

                if(batch) return sendRaw(transaction);

                const txResult = await sendRaw(transaction);
                if(!txResult) {console.error('Something messed up')}
                else console.log('Actually worked?')
            };
```

Comment: Can you show your code? What happens when you send the approve transaction? Is it going through?

Comment: The approve transaction is going through and is successful as reported on etherscan. Please check the post above, I have updated it with code.

Comment: Do you have a transaction hash? The code looks reasonable.

Comment: @Ismael yessir, here is the transaction hash for the approval function that doesn't work, after that is the hash for the transferFrom function: **0x75d86705c8c4bf8fca818e92c6f2f0303851afb57d1aa1efe5d8666d05dca9ed**, **0x03745369cb750f4739486ddd1e4a40339e133bbf11373a700969291d68488542**

Comment: @Ismael I should mention that the transferFrom function is called from the escrow contract, the function in the escrow contract that calls transferFrom is named deposit() which is what you'll see as the function run in the second transaction hash. Please let me know if you would like to see the smart contract code as well.

Comment: The first [tx](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x75d86705c8c4bf8fca818e92c6f2f0303851afb57d1aa1efe5d8666d05dca9ed) you are calling a method called `payOut(uint256)`. Either the txhash is wrong, you are calling the wrong method, or the wrong address.

Comment: @Ismael Seems like I copied over the wrong hashes, sorry! Here they are again. Approve function: **0x58ae7a11107b736f1d3178e1ef60ed25d0f536ff871c6bfe2e89c81eb1fe31b5**   Deposit(transferFrom) function: **0x03745369cb750f4739486ddd1e4a40339e133bbf11373a700969291d68488542**

Comment: @AbhiThosar Both transactions executed perfectly fine. Perhaps it fixed itself.

Comment: @Ismael That's what's bothering me, I've checked on Etherscan every time I've tried this and the transaction is successful, but when I check the allowance of the spender I'm approving, it is unchanged.

Comment: If both approve and transferFrom work then it is your getter that is returning an incorrect value.

Comment: I thought this would be the case, but I think there's 2 reasons as to why that cannot be: 1. The allowance function is "official" code from BokkyPooBah's ERC20 Token contract, and 2. I thought the exact same thing and tried running the payOut function which transfers the approved coins to another account, but as you saw in my mistakenly given transaction hash, it failed :/

Comment: @Ismael I guess you were right or the universe was feeling benevolent but I ran the same unchanged function again to test it without even checking the getter and it worked?? Thank you for your help anyways haha